# Make a backup of an open file with the most recent changes

Tags: linux, memory, vim, swap

How can I make a backup of a file that's open and is actively written to, furthermore how can I make a backup of said file with the latest changes done to it?

For a long time, I thought that whenever I write to a file, the .swp file that's created is basically the up-to-date file that's still in swap memory, such that if I write to a file, then backup the .swp file, I will have that file with up to date content.

I tried this earlier and it doesn't seem to work. So it either doesn't work the way I thought it does, or there's a time interval between writing something in an open file, and that change making it's way to the swap file. Are any of these assumptions correct?

Are the changes that are actively written in a file present somewhere else in memory?

What I want to do is make a script that will make a new backup to a file I'm actively writing to while I write to it, with all the changes up to that point, in case my pc crashes or something.

EDIT: I tried opening the file, writing something to it and then waiting like 1 minute before trying the .swp file, and it does indeed have the changes.

Answer (score 0):

`h undofile`

From my vimrc:

```
" Backup
set nobackup
set noswapfile
set nowritebackup
set undolevels=10000
set history=10000

if has('persistent_undo')
  set undodir=$v/undo
  set undofile
endif
```

And a script to map `<leader>b` to write file in ~/.vim/undo which is my `undodir` (I set `$v` -> `~/.vim` on my .bashrc on unix)

```
" b -> Backup file
function! Backup(s)
  " Backup path
  let bck_file = expand('$v/undo/bck_') . strftime('%y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
  " File path
  let bck_file .= '--' . substitute(expand('%:p:r'), '/', '_', 'g')
  " Extension
  let bck_file .= '-' . a:s . '.' . expand('%:e')
  silent execute a:s . 'write! ' . bck_file
  echom 'Backup lines ' . a:s . ' of file: $bck_file = ' . bck_file
endfunction
command! -range=% Backup call Backup('<line1>,<line2>')
" :BackView to feed backup path of the day in command line
command! -range=% BackupView call feedkeys(':e '
            \ . expand('$v/undo/bck_') . strftime('%y-%m-%d'))
nnoremap <leader>b :Backup<CR>
vnoremap <leader>b :Backup<CR>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you did here, and you did a poor job of explaining what this is lol, sorry

Comment: 2. I create a shortcut to map `,b` to write a backup file of the current file in `.vim/undo` in a file prepended by the date